# Is there a way to serialize Json Property name in Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, api, serialization, json.net

I have a class as shown below which I want to serialize such that the JSON key is the `JsonPropertyName` of the variable, but the serialized string has the variable name as the JSON key.

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization
public class TestClass
{
   [JsonPropertyName("tst")]
   public string Test{ get; set; }
}
```

Serializer uses Newtonsoft.Json

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new TestClass {Test = "some value"})
Console.writeLine(json)
```

- actual output: `{"Test":"some value"}`
- expected output: `{"tst":"some value"}`

Is there a way to serialize the object with property name as the key
`{"tst":"some value"}`

Comment: You would need custom converter - Json.Net does not use System.Text.Json attributes (and vice versa).

Comment: Does this work? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonpropertyname.htm

Comment: @crimson589 indeed that would work... but it is not what the question is asking (maybe it is what OP needs so - they definitely can [edit] question to clarify)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov well based on his example, he wants the key `Test` to become `tst`, this was achieved in the link i gave, the key `ReleaseDate` was turned to `release_date`

Comment: @crimson589 my example class uses the system.text.json package.  [JsonProperty] is only available in Newtonsoft.  However, the serializer is using the Json.net package which isn't able to comprehend [JsonPropertName] which is native to system.text.Json

Comment: @crimson589 to me (assuming OP knows what they are talking about) the question reads as "I have class normally serialized with Text.Json, but for some reason I need to use Json.Net but still want to get the same JSON output"... But indeed, you could be absolutely right, and OP is writing code by copy-pasting random pieces together (rude assumption... should flag my own comment for even thinking about such possibility).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you! I changed the package to Newtonsoft in both places and used [JsonProperty] instead of [JsonPropertyName], and it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Text.Json.Serialization Does not appear to work for JSON with NESTED classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66490082/system-text-json-serialization-does-not-appear-to-work-for-json-with-nested-clas)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use the `JsonProperty()` attribute and not the `JsonPropertyName()` attribute. You also have to include `Newtonsoft.Json` not `System.Text.Json` that is the JSON library used for .NET:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class TestClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="tst")]
    public string Test{ get; set; }
}
```