# How to deserialize string to C# model with nested models

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

I'm passing a [FromForm] string param to a .net 6 web api controller. Looks like this.

```
public async Task<Dictionary<int, ReturnDataModel>> GetData([FromForm] string sensorData)
```

I am deserializing the string to a model .. Looks like this.

```
Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSubmittedSensorDataModel>(sensorData);
```

It deserializes all stand alone POCO's without fail , but it won't process the ExposureInputs model... Just remains null. I know that if I was to put that those in this model, it would deserialize fine, but I was wondering why it won't deserialize in this manner?
The fields all align and are correct when I submit them. The mapping just doesn't seem to work for any model embedded in the base model. Is there a way to do this?

here's the model class

```
public record UserSubmittedSensorDataModel
 {
     public string? SensorType { get; init; }
     public string? ExposureType { get; init; }
     public ExposureInputsModel ExposureInputs { get; init; } // This won't deserialize
 }


 public record ExposureInputsModel
{
    public string? ExposureType { get; init; }
    public string? StandardTestMethod { get; init; }
    public string? OrganizationStandardNumber { get; init; }
    public string? ExposureLocation { get; init; }

}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? I haven't tested, but I believe you need to decorate the class with the appropriate attribute:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66490082/system-text-json-serialization-does-not-appear-to-work-for-json-with-nested-clas

Comment: Can you show us your `JSON` string that you are trying to de-serialize with the above `Model` structure?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this scenario because of some curiosity to see is there any binding issues while using immutable records as  input for API. It is working properly. All fields are properly binding. Probably  the issue is with below method signature.

```
public async Task<Dictionary<int, ReturnDataModel>> GetData([FromForm] 
string sensorData)
```

Please change the type of sensorData to UserSubmittedSensorDataModel ,
you can avoid manual deserialization.
In my case it is working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this works when testing with swagger, but doesn't work when posting from my Vue.js front end. It doesn't map correctly. Which doesn't technically solve my issue.. but close.

Comment: How can you know the `JSON` string without the OP mentioning it on the question? I sense if you need a discussion then have it internally and not here on S.O

Comment: @Rahul , It is not JSON . Do you noticed [FromForm] attribute and passing Model. Those information are enough for creating a test.

Comment: @DeepakKoshy grateful for the deep dive. You helped me isolate it in a way I didn't see before. I didn't post it in my question as I didn't think it was relevant, but the sensorData parameter is coming from a Vue front end POST request. The issue I was having is I was passing an array to deserialize instead of an object. Once I changed that and the object to fit the model, it works like it should

Answer (score 0):

When I posted the question, I thought all I needed was what I posted. A reply above helped me realize my own mistake.

I am passing the sensorData parameter via a vue.js POST request.

I initially was creating an array for the ExposureInputs model, but I changed it to an object and it now deserialezes correctly.

```
    this.exposureInputs = {
        exposureType: this.exposureType,
        standardTestMethod: input.isStandard.toString(),
        organizationStandardNumber: input.standardNumber,
      };
```

Grateful for the help