# .NET JsonDeserializer fails when I rename List<> property with JsonProperty

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize json that looks like this:

```
{
  "Total": 1,
  "Page": 1,
  "Products": [
    {
      "ID": "524c20a3-a8ec-44f2-9685-311f1f7d1498",
      "SKU": "Bread",
      "Name": "Baked Bread",
      "Category": "Other",
      "Brand": null,
      "Type": "Stock",
      ...
    }
}
// shortened here.  Full response comes from
   https://dearinventory.docs.apiary.io/#reference/product/product/get
```

Everything works fine if I make my object list this:

```
 public class PageProducts
  {
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
  }
```

but, it will fail if I try to change the **Products** property to a different name like below:

```
 public class PageProducts
  {
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Products")]
    public List<Product> Items { get; set; }
  }
```

What am I missing?  I've done this lots of times for other properties.  Is it something special with it being a List?

Thanks!

Comment: Changing the property name to `Item` and annotating it with the `[JsonProperty]` attribute will **NOT** in itself make the deserialization fail. Proof: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m4unmk Whatever your actual problem, it is **NOT** the JsonSerializer having a problem. What is missing? I don't know. I am not really that good with reading the tea leaves, given that all you have said about the actual failure of your program is that it fails...

Comment: Can you give the error that you are receiving? Or is the `Items` list `null` or empty after deserialization?  This information can help to identify the issue.

Comment: Figured it. Was not using [JsonConvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897579/newtonsoft-json-for-net-is-ignoring-jsonproperty-tags).

Comment: If you want to use System.Text.Json the attribute should be JsonPropertyName
[How to customize property names and values with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Text.Json.Serialization Does not appear to work for JSON with NESTED classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66490082/system-text-json-serialization-does-not-appear-to-work-for-json-with-nested-clas)

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide more information on exception/inner exception details. because the problem not in serializing. as example I made a different conditions and all serialized correctly.

```
void Main()
{
    string json = "{\"Total\":1,\"Page\":1,\"Products\":[{\"ID\":\"524c20a3-a8ec-44f2-9685-311f1f7d1498\",\"SKU\":\"Bread\",\"Name\":\"Baked Bread\",\"Category\":\"Other\",\"Brand\":null,\"Type\":\"Stock\"}]}";
    Console.Write(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PageProducts>(json));
    Console.Write(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PageProducts2>(json));
    Console.Write(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PageProducts3>(json));
    Console.Write(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PageProducts4>(json));
}

public class PageProducts
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class PageProducts2
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Products")]
    public List<Product> Items { get; set; }
}

public class PageProducts3
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public Product[] products { get; set; }
}
public class PageProducts4
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Products")]
    public Product[] items { get; set; }
}

public class Product{
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public string SKU {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Category {get;set;}
}
```

[image]